# How do I format my USB flash to FAT 16 on windows?

Tags: usb, fat16

This question has been asked before. I think it deserves a simpler, more direct answer.

Edit:
- Please post answers specific to Windows platform. No one wants to install Ubuntu just to format a flash drive.

Answer (score 2):

Use `format` in `diskpart`. For example:

```
diskpart
select volume E:
format fs=FAT
```

Note that the maximum volume size of FAT (as per `diskpart` allows, at least) is 4GB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there lots of ways to do this. One simple method i used was to partition my 16GB flash drive, created a 1GB and formatted it as FAT16, all done within MiniTool Partition Wizard.

Answer (score 0):

This has been asked before. The answer is `mkfs.vfat -F 16 <device>`
It does not get much more simpler than that.

Comment: This doesn't work on windows.

Comment: No OS was specified in the question,

Comment: Nor does the answer have a specified OS

Answer (score 0):

You could use a program such as this: http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html which in my opinion is the best partition manager (even the free version) it's easy and simple to use.